# What is the difference between Work item, boards and sprints in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Work Item i am able to see task and user story, I boards I am able to see only User story and in sprints i am able to see both. So what is the difference between them and for which purpose  we use boards and sprints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Azure DevOps work items are used to capture data. There are multiple work item types: Epic, Feature, User Story, Bug, Task, Code Review, etc. A work item type defines the fields, states and rules for each of these work items.

The Work Items and Query hub allow you to query through all work item types.

Work items are also used to represent the Product Backlog. A list of Epics, Features, User Stories and Bugs in a certain order.

The "Board" provides an alternative view of the product backlog by state, often referred to as a Kanban Board. On each card you can also visualize tasks.

The Sprint Backlog breaks down the work on the Product Backlog into tasks that can be picked up in a Iteration/Sprint. This view represents what used to be called the "Scrum board" in old revisions of the Scrum Guide.

Each of these views shows data about the work in progress, but each view shows it in different ways. You might look at the work in these different views depending on your need.

If you want to know what the most important upsoming work is, look at the Backlog view. Work at the top is the most likely to be picked up next sprint/iteration.

If you want to know the state of the work on the product backlog, look at the Board view, which can be used to show what work is refines, what work is ready to be picked up, what work is in progress etc.

If you need to know about the activities that need to be done, the tasks then either look at the Board view and extend the card to show the tasks or look at the Sprint view of the current sprint.

*Personally*, I mostly use the Board view nowadays since it's the most flexible way to view all the work in progress.